# reading and writing to the same file simultaneously in python

Tags: python, file-writing

Is it possible to read and write simultaneously to the same file? I have this chunk of code:

```
with open(total_f, 'w') as f:
    s= len(resu)
    #print s
    f.write ("the total number is {}\n".format(s))
    f.write('\n'.join(map(str, resu)))

with open(total_f ,'r') as f:
    content = f.read()
    count = content.count("FFFF")
    print count
```

but I need them to be together, because I want to write the result of `count` in `total_f`.

I tried to put in the read/write together like this:

```
with open(total_f, 'rw') as f:# i want to read and write at the same time
    s= len(resu)
    content = f.read()
    count = content.count("FFFF")  
    #print s
    f.write ("the total number is {}\n".format(s))
    f.write ("the total number is {}\n".format(count))
    f.write('\n'.join(map(str, resu)))
```

But it's still not working, and so I'm not sure if that's correct.

Comment: What happens when you run your code?

Comment: i have the result seperatly, am looking for a way to put in the open total_f as read as well, and write the result into the same file

Comment: I don't know what "i have the result seperatly" means.

Comment: i will edit the question now,

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what do you want to read from the written file and so I do not guarantee this answer will work as is: it is intended to show the workflow that you may use:

```
with open(total_f, 'w+') as f:
    s= len(resu)
    #print s
    f.write ("the total number is {}\n".format(s))
    pos_before_data = f.tell()
    f.write('\n'.join(map(str, resu)))

    f.seek(pos_before_data)
    content = f.read()
    count = content.count("FFFF")
    print count
```

The key is to open the file in `'w+'` mode and, **if necessary**, use `f.tell()` and `f.seek()` to navigate. Open in `'r+'` if file already exists and you *do not want to overwrite it*.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `contextmanager`:

```
import contextlib
@contextlib.contextmanager
def post_results(total_f, resu):
  with open(total_f ,'r') as f:
    content = f.read()
    count = content.count("FFFF")
  yield count
  with open(total_f, 'w') as f:
    s= len(resu)
    f.write ("the total number is {}\n".format(s))
    f.write('\n'.join(map(str, resu)))

with post_results('filename.txt', 'string_val') as f:
  print(f)
```

`contextmanager` creates a *enter* and *exit* sequence which enables the function to automatically perform the desired final sequence of execution. In this case, `count` needs to be garnered and printed and after, the value stored in `count` needs to be written to `total_f`.

Comment: While I really love the idea of jumping to creating to a context manager, I mean Python is about creating classes, it seems overpower when the 'r+' mode exists.

Comment: @Ajax1234, the "total_f" is only in  existent  after its written. I am writing a file to total_f from a list, now i need to get something from the file i wrote