# Can i use input while using write mode for files crud operation in Python?

Tags: python, file

```
"""10-3. Guest: Write a program that prompts the user for their name. When they
respond, write their name to a file called guest.txt."""

filename2 = "../Data/guest.txt"
with open(filename2, "w") as guest_info:
    filename = input(str(guest_info))
    for info in guest_info:
        print(f"name: {info}")
```

I already created empty txt file. I need to let user fill with info. How would you solve this?

```
10-3. Guest: Write a program that prompts the user for their name. When they
respond, write their name to a file called guest.txt."""

filename2 = "../Data/guest.txt"
with open(filename2, "w") as guest_info:
    filename = input(str(guest_info))
    for info in guest_info:
        print(f"name: {info}")
```

I was expecting, that input would work but it says it isn't readable.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the responses to this question: [reading and writing to the same file simultaneously in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48837560/reading-and-writing-to-the-same-file-simultaneously-in-python)

It is possible to perform read and write operations with w+, you may find it more straightforward to add the new entry in write mode, then open in read mode to check the contents.

Double-check how you are working with your input function. The value you pass into the str() function is the prompt that will be displayed. e.g. to prompt for a name and enter it into your file, the following is a common approach:

```
filename = input(str("what is your name? "))
guest_info.write(filename)
```